# Did Sanjaya and Barbarika see Krishna's universal form?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

We all know that Arjuna saw vishwaroop of Krishna in the mahabharata war but could Barbarika,(the grandson of Bheema, who watched the entire war from the mountain) and Sanjay see the vishwaroop?

Sanjaya was given divine eyes to see mahabharata war (which even Barbarika was seeing from the mountain). So, basically his divine eyes was to see mahabharata war and not for seeing the viswaroop. And Krishna freezed entire war area except Arjuna. Then how could Sanjay see the Viswaroop?

Answer (score 6):

There is no evidence to suggest that Barbarika saw Visvarupa. But yes, Sanjaya did see the Visvarupa of Sri Krishna which is evident from his following comments:

> 11.9 Sanjaya said O King, having spoken thus, thereafter, Hari [Hari: destroyer of ignorance along with its conseences.] (Krsna) the great Master of Yoga, showed to the son of Prtha the supreme divine form:
>
> 11.10 **Having many faces and eyes, possessing many wonderful sights, adorned with numerous celestial ornaments, holding many uplifted heavenly weapons**;
>
> 11.11 **Wearing heavenly garlands and apparel, anointed with heavenly scents, abounding in all kinds of wonder, resplendent, infinite, and with faces everywhere.**
>
> 11.12 **Should the effulgence of a thousand suns blaze forth simultaneously in the sky, that might be similar to the radiance of that exalted One.**
>
> 11.13 At that time, Pandava saw there, in the body of the God of gods, the whole diversely differentiated Universe united in the one (Cosmic form).
>
> 18.77 O king, **repeatedly recollecting that greatly extraordinary form of Hari, I am struck with wonder. And I rejoice again and again.**

These can not be communicated or recollected unless are seen personally.

I think he was shown this because of the grace of the Almighty Sri Krishna. If Sanjay was not allowed to see this, the whole world would have been deprived from some beautiful parts of Gita and may be many of us would not be able to believe in it if only what Arjuna saw was recorded.

So it seems another play of the ever- playful Sri Hari.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that both Barbarika and Sanjaya witnessed Mahabharata war. I'm not sure if the time was temporally frozen by Lord Krishna or not while showing His universal form. I don't know about Barbarika (will update answer if I find about him) but according to Mahabharata, Sanjaya saw Krishna's universal form.

From [MB, Bhishma parva, book - 6](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06002.htm),

> Vaisampayana continued.--"Upon his not wishing to see the battle but wishing to hear of it, Vyasa, that lord of boons, gave a boon to Sanjaya. (And addressing Dhritarashtra he said),--'This Sanjaya, O king, will describe the battle to thee. **Nothing in the whole battle will be beyond this one's eyes.' Endued, O king with celestial vision, Sanjaya will narrate the battle to thee. He will have knowledge of everything. Manifest or concealed, (happening) by day or by night, even that which is thought of in the mind, Sanjaya shall know everything.** Weapons will not cut him and exertion will not fatigue him. This son of Gavalgani will come out of the battle with life. As regards myself, O bull of Bharata's race, the fame of these Kurus, as also of all the Pandavas, I will spread. Do not grieve. This is destiny, O tiger among men. It behoveth thee not to give way to grief. It is not capable of being prevented. As regards victory, it is there where righteousness is.'"

So, Sanjaya was able to see everything and nothing happened beyond his vision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Shri Krishna gave divine eyes to see this battle and conclude it. His Whole Entire **Energy**(State) Can't be seen by physical eyes while **Shri Ved Vyas** gave divine eyes to see whole battle. In **Chapter 12 of Bhagavad Gita** he said to Dhritrashta "Shri Krishna showed his **Avinashi AnantVishwaswaroop**( Undestructable Unlimited Heads, Stomachs and many hands ) and Chaturbhujroop( Four armed Man ) to Arjun by giving divine eyes". Both are able to see his Avinashi AnantVishwaswaroop but he knows from Arjun that **Shri Krishna** shows his **Avinashi AnantVishwaswaroop**. Shri Krishna gave Divine eyes to see only Avinashi AnantVishwaswaroop. Barbrika conclude that Only one purush(man) is killed, won, loses and lives.

Comment: What is the basis of your conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Sanjaya's description of ViswaSwaroopa was received by Dhritharashtra  with fear and disdain. He surely saw it.

Krishna agreed that Babrika would see *everything* in the Mahabharatha war in a bargain that later on turned out to include ViswaSwaroopa from mountain top or Dhwaja Sthambam. It was a pre-condition ( preplanned arrangement).

Comment: A precondition including showing of Visvarupa? Did you get any mention of it in conversation of Sri Krishna with Varvarik?

Comment: Edited it. Krishna wanted to pre-empt Varvarik's participation as he had a potential to destroy Pandavas.